# Word disappears on closing one document via macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm hoping there's a simple solution here, but not being a coder I have no idea what the solution should be.

In MS Word I have a VBA userform that can either be submitted, skipped or discarded.  The present issue is with the "Discard" button.  Its purpose is to exit the form completely using 'ThisDocument.Close' so that nothing is erroneously submitted for review; however, when the user clicks this button to abandon the userform it seems to hide all other Word documents that may be open as well.  Word disappears from the Taskbar.  The documents do not close, and I know this because when I open Word afresh they are still open under the ribbon in View > Switch Windows.

The following is my code:

```
Private Sub CancelBtn_Click()

Dim SureCancel As Integer

SureCancel = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to abandon this sheet? _
Changes will not be saved!", vbYesNo)

If SureCancel = vbYes Then
    ThisDocument.Close wdDoNotSaveChanges
End If

End Sub
```

I have also tried to use `Application.Visible = True` after the `End If` to no avail.

Any help / ideas greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're closing the document containing the form, while the form is still open.  Try hiding the form before closing the document.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  Unfortunately it didn't work.  I did find a way around it though...

Comment: I've put the `Application.Visible = True` inside the `If` ahead of closing the document.  Now all I need to do is figure out how to do that only when there is something else open.  Once I've solved that I'll update this with an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a couple of minor additions to my code and it now does exactly what I want to.

```
Private Sub CancelBtn_Click()

Dim SureCancel As Integer

SureCancel = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to abandon this sheet? _
Changes will not be saved!", vbYesNo)

If SureCancel = vbYes Then
        If Documents.Count > 1 Then
            Application.Visible = True
        End If
    ThisDocument.Close wdDoNotSaveChanges
End If

End Sub
```

The `If Documents.Count > 1` clause checks whether anything else is open in Word and only if that is true does the Application then appear again, otherwise it quits.